# Borrar un objeto de un arraylist buscando por posicion

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy haciendo un trabajo y me piden Dar de baja partes de trabajo por un índice dado (posición en la colección).
Entonces tengo una clase parte de trabajo, y una clase empresa y una clase materiales(que no nos viene al cuento ahora). Se como se haría con un array el eliminar según la posición pero con un arraylist no se. Os pongo el código que llevo realizado.
clase empresa

```
public class Empresa {

private ArrayList<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes;

public Empresa(ArrayList<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes) {
    this.pilaDePartes = pilaDePartes;
}

public Empresa() {
    this.pilaDePartes = new ArrayList<ParteDeTrabajo>();
}

public ArrayList<ParteDeTrabajo> getPilaDePartes() {
    return pilaDePartes;
}

public void setPilaDePartes(ArrayList<ParteDeTrabajo> pilaDePartes) {
    this.pilaDePartes = pilaDePartes;
}

public ParteDeTrabajo buscarParte(String nombreTrabajador) {
    for (ParteDeTrabajo p1 : pilaDePartes) {
        if (p1.getNombreTrabajador().compareToIgnoreCase(nombreTrabajador) == 0) {
            return p1;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String aniadirParte(ParteDeTrabajo p) {
    pilaDePartes.add(p);
    return "parte añadido";
}

public String borrarParte(int posicion) {
    for(int i=0;i< pilaDePartes.size();i++){
        if(i==posicion)
       pilaDePartes[i]=

               }
}
```

Si fuera un array normal ese pilasdepartes[i] lo igualo a null y listo pero al ser un array listo no se que hacer

Answer (score 4):

El método [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) de `ArrayList` sirve para eso.

Acepta distintos parámetros.

Un índice (en tu caso)

```
lista.remove(3); // Elimina el elemento en el cuarto puesto, empieza por 0.
```

Un objeto:

```
lista.remove(empresaAEliminar); // Elimina la primera ocurrencia de empresaAEliminar.
```

En tu caso el método `borrarParte` sería así:

```
public void borrarParte(int posicion) {
    pilaDePartes.remove(posicion);
}
```

He cambiado el valor de retorno de `String` a `void` porque no estás devolviendo nada, pero si necesitas devolver algo cámbialo.

Comment: `lista.remove(3)` elimina el elemento de la cuarta posición no de la tercera.

Answer (score 3):

utiliza el método remove que implementa la interfaz List, no?

Por ejemplo:

`List<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList();
 arraylist.add(1); //añado un elemento de ejemplo
 arraylist.remove(0); //borra el elemento en de la primera posición`

Acceso a la posición 0 de un arraylist.

En tu caso quedaría así el método del borrado:

```
public String borrarParte(int posicion) 
{
    pilaDePartes.remove(i);     
}
```

La documentación oficial es esta.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: `get`es para acceder a un elemento, lo que se quiere es borrar de la lista

Comment: gracias estoy muy verde aun jaj y no sabia como hacerlo. Mi profesor es bastante malo y los apuntes peores

Comment: Perdona @PabloLozano no lo había visto bien. Ahora sí he corregido :)

Comment: Si tienes la posición a borrar, no necesitas recorrer el array, solo `remove(posicion);` es suficiente.

Comment: Cierto!! @ArianJM, lo corrijo!!